# Is there a list of financial assistance programs in Ontario, for the poor but not disabled?

Tags: ontario, charity, welfare-benefits

As nobody in my family is disabled, we probably don't qualify for Ontario Disability Support Program. But we're indigent, and I'm downcast to find out only about [OESP](https://redd.it/9cs3p0) today! I know about the big ones like Ontario Drug Benefit Program/Trillium Drug Program, [Ontario Works](https://www.mcss.gov.on.ca/en/mcss/programs/social/ow/), OSAP. But none of their websites mention OESP.

Where can I see a list of all such welfare programs?

Answer (score 3):

In Canada and the U.S., you can dial 2-1-1 on your phone to talk to someone about assistance programs.  These phones are usually staffed by the [United Way](https://www.unitedway.org/).

Besides the call-in service, they also maintain websites with information about assistance programs:

- Canada: [211.ca](http://211.ca/)
- U.S.: [211.org](http://www.211.org/)

These websites will direct you to more localized websites for help in your area.  For example, the Ontario 211 site is at [211ontario.ca](https://211ontario.ca/).